# Google Login PHP is not redirecting after authentication

Tags: php, authentication, google-signin

I am running an issue where after I authenticate the user, that it's redirecting me to the log in page again and not the home-page.php where it should display the user's google login information. I tried adding an exit(); after authentication like what this thread ([Why is my web not redirecting after Google Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246863/why-is-my-web-not-redirecting-after-google-login)) suggested but I still run into the same issue.

**Config.php**

```
<?php

// Google API configuration
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', '659848906740-qvoftv2sg9urfh5kt5a2hh3mcel57hsa.apps.googleusercontent.com');
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'Te3sltN31StU3zgmUQm0SBwR');
define('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL', 'https://cgi.sice.indiana.edu/~team03/team-03/Server/profile_log.php');

// Start session
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include Google API client library
require_once 'google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

// Call Google API
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('Login to Hair Identity');
$gClient->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$gClient->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$gClient->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL);

$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
 // Include configuration file 
 require_once 'config.php'; 
 session_start();

 if(isset($_GET['code'])){ 
     $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']); 
     $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken(); 
     header('Location: ' . filter_var(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); 
 } 

 if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){ 
     $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']); 
 } 
 

if($gClient->getAccessToken()){ 
     // Get user profile data from google 
     $gProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get(); 

     // Getting user profile info 
     $gData = array(); 
     $gData['oauth_uid']  = !empty($gProfile['id'])?$gProfile['id']:''; 
     $gData['first_name'] = !empty($gProfile['given_name'])?$gProfile['given_name']:''; 
     $gData['last_name']  = !empty($gProfile['family_name'])?$gProfile['family_name']:''; 
     $gData['email']      = !empty($gProfile['email'])?$gProfile['email']:''; 
     $gData['gender']     = !empty($gProfile['gender'])?$gProfile['gender']:''; 
     $gData['locale']     = !empty($gProfile['locale'])?$gProfile['locale']:''; 
     $gData['picture']    = !empty($gProfile['picture'])?$gProfile['picture']:''; 

     $userData = $gData; 

     // Storing user data in the session 
     $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData; 

     // storing user profile data in session
     if(!empty($userData)){ 

     $_SESSION["upic"]= '<img width="100" src="'.$userData['picture'].'">'; 
     $_SESSION["uid"]= '<p><b>Google ID:</b> '.$userData['oauth_uid'].'</p>'; 
     $_SESSION["uname"]= '<p><b>Name:</b> '.$userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'].'</p>'; 
     $_SESSION["uemail"]= '<p><b>Email:</b> '.$userData['email'].'</p>'; 
     $_SESSION["logout"]= '<p><a href="logout.php"><b>Logout</b></a></p>'; 

     header("Location: home-page.php");


     }else{ 
         $out_error = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>'; 
         echo $out_error;
     } 
 }else{ 
    // Get login url 
    $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl(); 

    echo "<center>";
    echo "<h1>Continue logging in with Google </h1>";
    // google login button 
    $login_image = '<a href="'.filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL).'">
    <img src="images/google-sign-in-btn.png" alt=""/></a>'; 
    echo $login_image;
    echo "</center>";
 } 
 ?> 
 
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
 </html>
```

**home-page.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Account</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["uname"])){ 
    
 echo "<h1>Your Google Details </h1>";

 echo   $_SESSION["upic"];
 echo   $_SESSION["uid"];
 echo   $_SESSION["uname"];
 echo   $_SESSION["uemail"];
 echo   $_SESSION["logout"];
    
}else{
    
    header("index.php");
}

?>
</center>
</body>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
// Include configuration file
require_once 'config.php';

// Remove token and user data from the session
unset($_SESSION['token']);
unset($_SESSION['userData']);

// Reset OAuth access token
$gClient->revokeToken();

// Destroy entire session data
session_destroy();

// Redirect to homepage
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes):

> Note:
>
> Most contemporary clients accept relative URIs as argument to »
> Location:, but some older clients require an absolute URI including
> the scheme, hostname and absolute path. You can usually use
> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an
> absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Try this.

Comment: Hello, where do I put this within my code?

Comment: Where you want to make the redirect, but of course, change the `$extra` variable to the file you want.

Comment: I changed my code ```header("Location: home-page.php");``` to your code provided and changed the $extra variable to my home-page.php. And it's still running into the same issue. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You sure your code is stepping inside this condition `if(!empty($userData)){ `?

Answer (score 0):

The `header("Location: home-page.php");` code in index.php is correct and should be the page you want your redirect to, in this case mine is the page that displays the google information of the user. The issue was in the config.php where your Google_redirect_URL should be the file that your google button is connected to, in my case being index.php. You also need to add that URL to your Google console so you don't get a mismatch error.